# pushing view controller onto uiimagepickercontroller causes image picker buttons to be misnamed

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a uiimagepicker controller where i push a tableview controller ontop of inside:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
        editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
```

When I click back on the tableview controller nav bar it should take me to the preview view( i assume).  Instead it takes me to a view where i can take a new picture with a toolbar on the bottom that has "Retake" and "Use" buttons.  The problem is, the image preview is no longer there, instead it is in photo taking mode with the "Retake" button cancelling the image picker and the "Use" button snapping a photo.  The button titles don't represent the actions.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your queries ??It's not clear what you want to do..Upto some extend what I understand, YOu just want to have preview for the image you don't want to capture the image??

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a step.  The imagePickerController is used for picking images.  After you take the image you have to do something with it (store it in your application or save it to the camera roll), then you can push the table view controller on top of it.  When you press the back button and the to the imagetPicker controller is called, it calls on the camera and waits for you to pick another image.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html):

> The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception.
>   In iOS 3.1 and later, you can assign a custom view to the `cameraOverlayView` property and
>   use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the
>   camera interface and your code.

It would seem that includes pushing view controllers onto the UIImagePickerController.

Comment: In the facebook app, after you take a photo the imagepicker is shifted to the left?  How is this possible?  I only can see this being done if you push a view on top of the picker navigation controller. thx

Comment: It can do other animations by present view controller, for example shift to the left.